# Bootstrap - 3 columns in one row, titles outside of the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am making a website and the client is very specific about how he wants it.

In one of the sections he asked me to put three columns. The first two columns must be a title with its corresponding text and the third one must be an image.
So the only challange here for me was to make the third column adapt its height to the other two columns. But after some research and using flexbox I accomplished it.

However, when I showed it to the client he said that he wanted the image to adapt only to the text and not to the whole column. He wants the titles of the other two columns to be outside. Since I don't know if I made myself clear, here is an image of what he wants: [image]

Notice how the image starts where the subtitles start. So the actual question would be: **how do I place the titles "Buy" and "Sell" centered and above each column?**

Here is the code I used when I thought that the image started where the titles start:

```css
#buy_sell main{
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.buy_sell_photoColumn{
  background: url('../img/buy_sell_photo.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.buy_sell_text h2{
  text-align: center;
  color: #0bbacf;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buy_sell_text h3{
  text-align: center;
  color: #43727c;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'AvenirNext-Regular';
}

#buy_sell .buy_sell_text p{
    color: #43727c;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'AvenirNext-Regular';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buy_sell_text p:nth-of-type(4){
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

#buy_sell .buy_sell_text ul{
  color: #43727c;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'AvenirNext-Regular';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#buy_sell main>div{
  display: flex;
}

.buy_sell_text, .buy_sell_photoColumn{
  flex: 1;
}

.buy_sell_text ul{
  padding: 0;
}

#buy_sell .buy_sell_text ul{
  color: #43727c;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'AvenirNext-Regular';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;

   text-indent: 2px;
   list-style-position: outside;
}

#buy_sell .sellProperty p{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#buy_sell .sellProperty li{
  margin: 5px 40px;
}

#buy_sell .sellProperty li:before{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  content:"\25B6";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: #00b6d0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<main class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 buy_sell_text textWrapper">
                    <h2>BUY</h2>
                    <h3>subtitle here</h3>
                    <p>lorem ipsum</p>

                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et do.</p>

                    <p> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volupta</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 buy_sell_text sellProperty textWrapper">
                    <h2>SELL</h2>
                    <h3>subtitle here!</h3>
                    <p>here is what I offer:</p>

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            lorem ipsum
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            lorem ipsum
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            lorem ipsum
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            Lorem ipsum
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 buy_sell_photoColumn">
                </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer and I will post it here just in case anyone in the future has the same problem.

You have to give `main` a padding of 100px (or however much your design requires), and you have to give your `h2`'s the following style:

```
.buy_sell_text h2{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
 }`
```

This way the titles will appear to leave their columns, there will still be padding-top and padding-bottom, and using flexbox the image will adapt to the other two column's text height.

```
#buy_sell main>div{
  display: flex;
}

.buy_sell_text, .buy_sell_photoColumn{
  flex: 1;
}
```

I hope this was useful for any of you.
Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant approach, but you could simply make a matching "set" of columns in a new row above, and put the titles in that.

ie. Duplicate that entire row. Then in the first copy delete everything except the titles... easy to think of, hard to explain haha

Either that or give the titles themselves a fixed height, and use that same height as padding on the column with the image.

Given he sounds like a "challenging" client, you had also better anticipate/check how he wants it to look when it collapses :(

Comment: Hey, so I followed your suggestion and you are right, it isn't the most elegant way. As you mentioned, the problem is that it is not responsive, so in 992px I had to add this media query, which makes it even less elegant: '.sell_title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
  }

  .sellProperty{
    margin-top: 50px;
  }'

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be responsive? The row above would simply echo the row below? I guess I don't understand something.

Comment: Well, they are two different rows. When you make the browser smaller the first row breaks down in three parts, and **then** the second row breaks down in three parts, so it looks like this:
Title A
Title B
Blank
Text A
Text B
Image